# Stopping Jquery timer when it reaches 0

Tags: php, jquery

I am in need of help.
I am making a count down script for my game website which grabs the end time from the database and counts down until the current time is equal to the database time.
But I can not seem to get it to stop when it hits 0.
I have looked into setTimeout() and I do not understand how I would get this to work.

Also when the page is refreshed it starts the timer again from the database time. How would i either, update the database to the time left or stop the timer from refreshing.

Thanks in adavance. Below is the script I have so far

```
<?php
include "header.php";

?>
 <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var curTime = Math.floor( (new Date()).getTime() / 1000 ); // replaced with PHP time(), presumably
var endTime = Math.floor( (new Date()).getTime() / 1000 ) + <?php echo $user_class->jail;?>;

function tick( )
{
    var secs = endTime - cTime;
    var mins = Math.floor( secs / 60 );
    secs %= 60;
    document.getElementById("ticker").innerHTML = 
         mins + " minutes, " + secs + " seconds";
    ++curTime;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="setInterval(tick,1000); tick();">
<h3>Time remaining is <span id="ticker"></span></h3>

</body>
</html>
```

My database is currently updated every 1 minute through a cron so it can be out due to the cron. But I was wondering if there was a way to update the database through the countdown instead so it will be acurate as other the timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this if() at the end of your tick() function

```
if(endTime < curTime) clearInterval(i);
```

And change your onload value to this.

```
<body onload="i = setInterval(tick,100); tick();">
```

clearInterval should make the job.
Be carefull with this line

```
var secs = endTime - cTime;
```

Which probably contains a typo on your cTime var

```
var secs = endTime - curTime;
```

Comment: thank you this has got the timer stopping when it reaches 0 but i had to change <body onload="i = setInterval(tick,100); tick();"> to <body onload="i = setInterval(tick,1000); tick();"> as it was counting down to quickly for seconds

Comment: Oh yes I reduced it to 100 to test on my fiddle. I forgot to set it back to 1000, Apologies :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use clearInterval() function. Pretty good example can be found at

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

When you call `setInterval` function, it returns a handler of created timer (its just a number). And you can use this handler to stop timer by passing it to `clearInterval` function

example:

```
timer = setTimeout(function () { console.log('hello'); }, 5000);
...
// This will stop timer
clearInterval(timer);
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code a bit, one shouldn't mix html/js/css/php too much.

File: **xxx.php:**

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Time remaining is <span id="ticker"></span></h3>
<input id="end_time" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $user_class->jail; ?>" />

<script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

File: **scripts.js**:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var timer;
    var curTime = Math.floor( (new Date()).getTime() / 1000 ); // replaced with PHP time(), presumably
    var endTime = Math.floor( (new Date()).getTime() / 1000 ) + document.getElementById('end_time').value;

    function tick() {
        var secs = endTime - curTime;
        var mins = Math.floor( secs / 60 );
        secs %= 60;
        document.getElementById("ticker").innerHTML = 
             mins + " minutes, " + secs + " seconds";
        ++curTime;
        if (curTime > endTime) {
            stopTimer();
        }
    }
    function startTimer() {
        timer = setInterval(tick,1000);
    }    
    function stopTimer() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
    startTimer();
};
```